# MongoDB/pymongo calculate difference of two times in minutes

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to calculate the difference between two timestamps in mongodb.

With MySQL it can easily be achieved using this query

`SELECT ROUND((TIME_TO_SEC(NOW()) - TIME_TO_SEC(lastseen))/60) AS minutes` where lastseen is a timestamp column.

Here is my schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa329cb0b717a0f637b0937"),
    "username" : "admin@mans.com",
    "token" : "1085bbc68a",
    "realname" : "Administrator",
    "lastseen" : ISODate("2018-03-09T19:41:47.552Z")
}
```

How can I get the time difference between `lastseen` in the document and `datetime.datetime.now()` in minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`$subtract` aggregation query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) can be used to find the difference of two dates. *e.g*

```
query = [{
    '$project': {
        'username': 1,
        'date_diff_mins': { 
             '$divide': [
                 {'$subtract': [datetime.now(), '$lastseen']},
                 1000 * 60
             ] 
        } 
    }
}]
db.collection.aggregate(query)
```